# Error QODBC driver not loaded when trying to connect to an MSSQL database from QGIS 3.4.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: qgis, sql-server, odbc

I have installed QGIS Desktop (latest one: 3.4.3 Madeira) along with the unixODBC-dev for SQL Server 2017 (following instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)). I used sqlcmd from msql-tools and successfully connected to the database server. I opened QGIS Desktop and when I tried to connect to an MSSQL database I received the following message:

```
Warning: QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded 
Warning: QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QSPATIALITE
```

I went searching for a driver and I found out that I am supposed to build the driver (!).

Assuming that QGIS Desktop is loading the available drivers from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers`, I wen on and installed Qt5.10.1, built the ODBC driver using [these instructions](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/sql-driver.html#qodbc) and copied the resulting `libqsqlodbc.so` to the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers`.
This directory now contains the following:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  65048 Apr 12  2018 libqsqlite.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 alas root 123784 Jan  4 20:03 libqsqlodbc.so*
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  71832 Dec 22 06:50 libqsqlspatialite.so
```

I run again QGIS Desktop, I tried again to connect to the database server and I got again the same error.

My questions are:

a. Is there an easy way to add the QODBC driver to QGIS Desktop?

b. Am I doing something wrong above?

c. IS THERE ANY way to make QGIS Desktop in linux work with a SQL Server???

Comment: Finally what I ended up doing is download the qgis docker image, run it and copy out the libqsqlodbc.so library :-). Not perfect but it works. I am guessing that if I wanted to build the drivers myself I should invest some time in checking to see how they do it in their dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found is the one mentioned in my comment above and since there is no answer I think it is the only way of acquiring the library without building it.

So follow these steps:

1. go to https://hub.docker.com/r/qgis/qgis/tags
2. find the release you are interested in (either final-xxx or release-xxx)
3. download the image (docker pull) and create a container
4. navigate to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers` and copy out the library